# Dynamic edge addition in network using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, networkx

I am trying to simulate a network growth by having edges connecting to different nodes. The following code, when run, displays the entire sequence of edges and nodes simultaneously. **But how do i show one edge getting added to another after a delay of n units of time (in the same graph).** I understand i have to use 'animation' package but am not sure how

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f1(g):

    nodes = set([a for a, b in g] + [b for a, b in g])

    G=nx.Graph()

    for node in nodes:
       G.add_node(node)

    for edge in g:
       G.add_edge(edge[0], edge[1])

    pos = nx.shell_layout(G)

    nx.draw(G, pos)

    plt.show()

g = [(10, 11),(11, 12),(12, 13), (13, 15),(15,10)]
f1(g)
```

I hope the intendation is correct. When the code is run, a graph does show up, but how to have each edge appearing one after the other, instead of appearing simultaneously.

Comment: The code you posted does not run -- could you please formulate your question as [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I almost missed your edit -- next time it is best to answer to the comment. If you start your comment with and `@`followed by a username, that user will receive a note in his mail box.

Answer (score 2):

Basically there is already an answer to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18232645/2454357), but I decided to write another answer that is tailored to your specific problem. Instead of using `nx.draw()`, I use `nx.draw_networkx_edges` and `draw_networkx_nodes`, which return a `LineCollections` and a `PathCollection`, respectively. These can then be altered in several ways, for instance you can change the color of each line segment in a `LineCollection`. In the beginning I set the colors of all edges to `white` and then I use a `matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation` to change these segment colors to `black` one by one at given time intervals. Once all edges are black, the animation starts over. Hope this helps.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

g = [(10, 11),(11, 12),(12, 13), (13, 15),(15,10)]

fig = plt.figure()

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from(g)
G.add_nodes_from(G)

pos = nx.shell_layout(G)
edges = nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, edge_color = 'w')
nodes = nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_color = 'g')

white = (1,1,1,1)
black = (0,0,0,1)

colors = [white for edge in edges.get_segments()]

def update(n):
    global colors

    try:
        idx = colors.index(white)
        colors[idx] = black
    except ValueError:
        colors = [white for edge in edges.get_segments()]

    edges.set_color(colors)
    return edges, nodes

anim = FuncAnimation(fig, update, interval=150, blit = True) 

plt.show()
```

The result looks like this:

[image: result of the above code]

Comment: So white and black color edges are overlapping the each other!! Thanks a lot!!!