# How to update the color of network during an animation

Tags: animation, colors, networkx

I'd like to write a program to animate fixation process in special network. During the animation, in each frame the color of nodes must be change by a special function. I wrote the following code, but it draw the network in each frame again that it's not my favor. I need a fixed network that just the color of nodes changes in each frame. But I don't know how do I code it!!! Is anybody knows how do I fixed it?

```
    import numpy as np
    import networkx as nx
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.close('all')
    import matplotlib.animation as animation

    G = nx.complete_graph(10)

    plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [7.50, 3.50]
    plt.rcParams["figure.autolayout"] = True

    fig = plt.figure()

    def animate(frame):
       fig.clear()
       colors_of_nodes = CON[frame, 0:N]    # CON is a matrix that create during a 
       #process that I create in another code
       nx.draw(G, node_color = colors_of_nodes, with_labels=True)
       return colors_of_nodes

       fig.set_tight_layout(False)

       anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames = rows, interval=500, 
       repeat=False, blit = True)

    plt.show()
```

I changed something as a comment that I get, and now the network fixed, but the animate function doesn't work :( . This is the new code:

```
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))

    pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
    colors_of_nodes = 'blue'
    nodes = nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos, node_color = 
    colors_of_nodes)
    edges = nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos)
    labels = nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos)

    def animate(frame):
       colors_of_nodes = CON[frame, 0:N]
       nodes.set_array(colors_of_nodes)
       return nodes


    anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames = rows, 
    interval=500, repeat = False)


    plt.show()
```

How can I able to solved the problem?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18229563/using-networkx-with-matplotlib-artistanimation) should help

Comment: Thanks, I checked and now I fixed the network, but the function "animate" doesn't work now :(